# How do I turn off passwords to log in and resume?

Tags: password

When I turn on and waking asks for a password, then again, always twice.  I want to turn OFF the passwords and not have to enter one at all when waking or turning on, please advise.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to log in automatically when you turn on your PC, evoke dash (press "Super" or "Win" key) then type "login" and click on "Login Screen" icon, then tick on "Log in automatically" option

You can also turn off locking the screen for Screensaver if you type "Screensaver" in dash, then un-select "Lock screen" option

Answer (score 0):

- Click on the Gear icon in the top right.
- Go to `System Settings>Brightness and Lock`
- Uncheck `Require my password when waking from suspend`

Works in Gnome and Unity.